# Regex - orderless extraction of string

Tags: regex, splunk

I have 2 strings which are 2 records

```
string1 = "abc/BS-QANTAS\\/DS-12JUL15\\dfd"
string2 = "/DS-10JUN15\\/BS-AIRFRANCE\\dfdsfsdf"
```

BS is booking airline
DS is Date

I want to use a single regex and extract the booking source & date. Please let me know if it is feasible.
I have tried lookaheads and still couldn't achieve

The target language is Splunk and not Javascript.
Whatever may be the language please post I'll give a try in Splunk

Comment: For string1, you want QANTAS and 12JUL15?  and for string 2 you want 10JUN15 and AIRFRANCE?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you've tried lookahead, what about lookbehind?

```
(?<=BS-|DS-)(\w+)
```

Tested at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cK0pQ1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more scalable (and more readable, IMO) alternative to [miroxlav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764010/20938):

```
(?:\/BS-(?P<source>\w+)|\/DS-(?P<date>\w+)|[^\/\v]+)+
```

I'm assuming the fields you're interested in always start with a slash.  That allows me to use `[^/]+` to safely consume the junk between/around them.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ9lO5/2)

This is effectively three regexes in one, wrapped in a group, to give each one a chance to match in turn, and applied multiple times.  If the first alternative matches, you're looking at a "source airline" field, and the name is captured in the group named "source".  If then second alternative matches, you're looking at the date, which is captured in the "date" group.

But, because the fields aren't in a predetermined order, the regex has to match the whole string to be sure of matching both fields (in fact, I should have used start and end anchors--`^` and `$`--to enforce that; I've added them below).  The third alternative, `[^/]+`, allows it to consume the parts that the first two can't, thus making an overall match possible.  Here's the updated regex:

```
^(?:\/BS-(?P<source>\w+)|\/DS-(?P<date>\w+)|[^\/\v]+)+$
```

...and the updated [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ9lO5/4).  As noted in the comment, the `\v` is there only because I'm combining your two examples into one multiline string and doing two matches.  You shouldn't need it in real life.

Comment: could you please explain to me how "|[^\/\v]+" actually working on this regexp? Alone this part and "|" is clear, however I'm not sure why the not-needed part is mentioned in regexp, how could it be useful. Checked on your demo, but still not clear.
Also could you tell me why \v need instead of \s ?

Comment: Actually, the `\v` was an artifact of the way I was testing the regex: treating the input as one two-line string instead of two strings.  The `\v` prevented it from matching the line separator.  `\s` would have worked just as well, since the line separator was the only whitespace.  (In RegexBuddy, where I worked out the solution, I used the "Line by line" option to treat each line as a separate input.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why "|[^\/\v]+" is useful? On regex101.com with your solution it gave the solution in 2 match, while without it would give in 4. The 2 match (your solution) I guess means a much faster run through, but I don't understand clearly why does it works this way.

Comment: Efficiency is not an issue; the regex must consume each complete line in one match, saving the two desired parts in the named groups, "source" and "date".  I've added some explanatory text to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you both strings filled either in match groups `airline1`+`date1` or in `airline2`+`date2`:

```
((BS-(?<airline1>\w+).*DS-(?<date1>[\w]+))|(DS-(?<date2>[\w]+).*BS-(?<airline2>\w+)))
```

[>> view at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aQ9lO5/1)

Since there are only 2 groups, I used simple permutation.

This regex will take last of occurrences, if there are more. If you need earliest one (using lookbehind), let me know.